# Wi-Fi network interface - Linux command not working

Tags: arch-linux, wifi

I am trying the command:

```
ip link set dev wlp3s0 down
```

to bring down the interface 'wlp3s0' (which is Wi-Fi in my case) down which works. But when I try to bring the interface back up with the command:

```
ip link set dev wlp3s0 up
```

The interface 'wlp3s0' does not come back up.

In fact, I have to use the GUI button for 'GNOME Network Manager' (which is located below when I click the volume control icon) for turning off the Wi-Fi and then connecting to it again manually, which automatically does the job.

Why is the command to bring the network interface back up not working (which in my case happens to be 'wlp3s0')?

I am using: 4.7.1-1-ARCH #1 SMP PREEMPT x86_64 system. Arch Linux.

**Note:**

I have been searching the Internet for this problem and some posts have suggested that this might be a hardware problem. My Wireless driver chipset information is as follows:

```
$ lspci | grep -i wireless
03:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You question is **why** it is not working.  Remember that the OSI network system is composed of several layers: physical (cable/radio), link (ethernet/802.11), network (IP), transport (TCP), and some higher ones that are often mangled together.  When you do.

```
ip link set dev wlp3s0 down
```

It does bring the link layer (OSI link layer) down.  This means that all higher layers will be brought down as well: the IP is forgotten, any TCP connections are broken.

```
ip link set dev wlp3s0 up
```

Does bring the link layer up (given that there is no encryption involved, see extra encryption note below).  After running it you should see:

```
$ ip link show
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
2: wlp3s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP mode DORMANT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:22:43:1b:ae:46 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

`wlp3s0` should be either in the state `DORMANT` or `UP` (depending if there is traffic coming through at the moment you run the command).  For all link layer purposes it is up, `ip` did what you asked it.

Now that you have a link layer connection you need to use a DHCP client to acquire an IP from a nearby DHCP server (normally a home router).  Arch uses `dhcpcd` as the DCHP client.

```
dhcpcd wlp3s0
```

Will give you an IP (and occupy your current terminal since it is not running in daemon mode without the `-b` flag).

---

#### Encryption note

Most wireless connections are not plain, they use either WEP or WPA/WPA2.  In such case, to establish a link layer, there is more work than plain:

```
ip link set dev wlp3s0 up
```

`iw` can deal with WEP encryption by specifying a key to be used by a certain interface.  After which `ip link set` will be able to establish a link layer connection.

WPA (and WPA2) requires a much more involved process with key negotiation.  For WPA `wpa_supplicant` is used, it wraps around `ip` to build all necessary messages with the router and then sets the link layer up.

Note that neither `iw` or `wpa_suppicant` will not provide you with an IP.

Also,

```
ip link set dev wlp3s0 down
```

Will happily drop a link layer connection configured with `iw` or made with `wpa_supplicant`, this is because dropping a link layer does not involve any encryption function.  It just tells the router: I'm not talking to you anymore, forget about me.

---

#### NetworkManager

Now, `networkmanager` is an even higher wrapper.  It uses `ip` for plain connections, `wpa_supplicant` for encrypted connections, and runs `dhcpcd` (or its own in-built DHCP client if it cannot find `dhcpcd`) automatically when a link layer is established.

In other words `networkmanager` does **a lot** behind the scenes.

Comment: `dhcpcd wlp3s0` appended after `ip link set dev wlp3s0 up` connects to the network and I don't have to deal with the encryption probably because the network is remembered/saved. Can you please suggest some resources where I can learn about Linux Networking apart from https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Network_configuration. Excellent answer!

Comment: @Arun - Yup, `iw` configuration is semi-permanent (with some dependence on hardware).  As of how to get practice: to be fair with you, I simply used my Arch laptop without using NetworkManager for a year (as an experiment in learning).  Yet, I had a decent knowledge of the OSI model first and a lot of debugging practice, for that I strongly recommend [practical packet analysis](https://www.nostarch.com/packet2.htm).  Without that I'd probably give up on my experiments with arch.